# How to read Arduino float values on OSX with Bluetooth LE (BLE mini module)

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

The SimpleControls example of the Red Bear Labs BLE Mini module (https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS/tree/master/Examples/SimpleControls_OSX) enables to send analog readings (e.g. temperature sensor) from an Arduino to iOS / OSX with following Arduino code:

```
uint16_t value = analogRead(ANALOG_IN_PIN)
BLEMini_write(0x0B);
BLEMini_write(value >> 8);
BLEMini_write(value);
```

However, I tried to convert the raw analog readings (e.g. 162) into actual temperature reading (e.g. degree celsius / 27.15) and transmit the conversion to iOS / OSX, but on OSX I just read strange values (e.g. 13414). The Arduino code I used is following:

```
  int reading = analogRead(ANALOG_IN_PIN);
  float voltage = reading * 5.0;
  float temp = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;
  int tempINT = temp;
  uint16_t value = tempINT;
  BLEMini_write(0x0B);
  BLEMini_write(value >> 8);
  BLEMini_write(value);
```

The code-part of the OSX-app is following:

```
-(void) bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *)data length:(int)length
{
    NSLog(@"Length: %d", length);

    // parse data, all commands are in 3-byte
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=3)
    {
       NSLog(@"0x%02X, 0x%02X, 0x%02X", data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2]);

        if (data[i] == 0x0A) // Digital In data
        {
            if (data[i+1] == 0x01)
                lblDigitalIn.stringValue = @"HIGH";
            else
                lblDigitalIn.stringValue = @"LOW";
        }
        else if (data[i] == 0x0B) // Analog In data
        {
            UInt16 Value;

            Value = data[i+2] | data[i+1] << 8;
            lblAnalogIn.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Value];
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem are "float" or converted "int" values and if someone could help me to solve this problem I would be really happy!

Answer (score 0):

All characteristic data is just bytes. Once a characteristic's data has been read it is up to the central app to convert the data to an appropriate format (as described by the peripheral's manufacturer or some characteristics also contain a format descriptor which will describe out to format its data.)